# How can I set up fragment cache if I'm using pagination and other params in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm using `devise`, `kaminari`, and `dalli(memcached)`.
I've just tried to implement caching when it's loading `http://example.com/communities?sort=popular`

I tried to code just like below. However it seems cache storing is not working.
It looks like it's still sending SQL every time it reloads the page...

What's wrong?

Then if possible, I'd like to clear all the stored caches that contains the string "community_index_sort_by_" when after the user made or edited "Community" record.

**config/environment/development.rb**

```
...
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
...
```

**community_controller.rb**

```
def index

    @key = "community_index_sort_by_" + params[:sort].to_s + "_page_" + params[:page].to_s

    if params[:sort] == 'popular'
        unless Rails.cache.fetch(:controller => "communities", :action => "index",  :action_suffix => @key)
            @communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("cached_votes_up DESC")
        end
    elsif params[:sort] == 'latest'
        @communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

I haven't touched any in view files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the cache fragment get created in the view with a cache call?

In the view, don't forget to include the params in the key, like the page offset:

```
<% cache 'the_cache_fragment_key' do %>
...the view...
<% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
unless fragment_exist?('cache_fragment_key')
 ...cache fragment doesn't exist, make a call for it...
end
```

This rails cast might be helpful.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching

For clearing the cache when updates are made rails sweepers are pretty helpful. You can define methods for model methods or controller actions. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers

Comment: Thanks this looks pretty useful to me. I have a question. Assuming there is a Post model, in which the users write comments almost like chats frequency(It means super busy) In this case, I wouldn't do caching and sweeping Post? Because, every seconds, cache will be deleted and re-created in a moment over and over again?

Comment: I have to know a litte bit more about the user case, but yeah it would probably even cause conflicts. Maybe use ajax to update the page?